# tkinter - Displaying text on canvas for a certain time period

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating GUI with `tkinter`.  (I use `tkinter 8.6`, `python 3.7.9`, `windows 10`)
When the button is clicked, I would like it to **display the text "registered" for 2 seconds**.

The following code works fine if the `*** code block ***` is commented out. It just displays the text when the button is clicked.

However, when I run the code with the `*** code block ***`, it **does not** even **display the text at all when the button is clicked and no error is raised** (I also tried `root.after(2000, my_canvas.delete(msg))` instead of the `*** code block ***`, and it's the same.)

What might be the cause of this? Any idea how to fix the issue?

---

#### Code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import * 
import time

root = Tk()

bg = PhotoImage(file='bg.png')
my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=185)
my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
my_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=bg, anchor=("nw")) 

def button_click():
    msg = my_canvas.create_text(100, 80, anchor="nw", fill="darkgreen", font=('Meiryo', 10, 'bold'), text="registered")
   
   #******** code block ***********
   # After 2 seconds, delete the text displayed 
    timeout = 2
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() < start + timeout:
        pass
    my_canvas.delete(msg)
   #*********************************
 
button1 = Button(root, text="register", command=button_click)
button1_window = my_canvas.create_window(120, 100, anchor="nw", window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are countless questions on this site related to timing. Do some research on the `after` method in tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very very close, you just have the arguments in the wrong place! You need to do this:

```
root.after(2000, my_canvas.delete, msg)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Any idea why the `*** code block***` does not work? First display, then do nothing for 2 seconds, and then delete the text displayed. It seems to work theoretically?

Comment: @koyamashinji you can't put any blocking loop inside a GUI because it blocks the GUI mainloop(), which is needed to update the screen, respond to the OS, respond to mouse movements, etc, etc... Your code would work in a procedural style, but tkinter (and most GUIs) are written as event driven style.